# Interprocess signalling : POSIX Semaphores/Shared memory vs TCP Socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, optimization, semaphore

I am making an application where it has to communicate with another process on the same machine.I need to signal an error from a root level process to the UI process. For that I am using semaphore. Kernel level process runs in a loop and on error, it locks the semaphore and writes the type of error in a shared memory segment. While the UI process monitors the semaphore in a loop, if it finds the semaphore is locked, it will notify the user of the error with the error type in the shared memory segment.

```
//err_sem= named semaphore
P1_root_lvl()
{
while(1)
{
    //Do Work

    if(error_type1)
    {
        err_flag=true;
        sem_trywait(&err_sem);
        shared_mem=type1;
    }
    else if(error_type2)
    {
        err_flag=true;
        sem_trywait(&err_sem);
        shared_mem=type2;
    }
    else if(ok_state==true && err_flag==true)
    {
        sem_post(&err_sem);
        err_flag=false;
    }

}
}

P2_UI()
{
long sleep_time=10000
while(1)
{
    sem_getvalue(&err_sem,ok)
    if(ok==1)
    {
        //All OK
    }
    else if(ok==0)
    {
        err_type=shared_mem;
    }
    usleep(sleep_time);
}
}
```

P1 is running on high priority.
I have many other modules running in the system at the same time.

1. What is the performance difference when I increase/decrease the `sleep_time`?
2. What is the performance difference if I use sockets to signal the UI process (P1 as client and P2 as server)?
3. What else I can do to optimise this mechanism i am using?

Comment: interview question?

Comment: Well, shared memory between threads is something error prone and new languages like Dart is removing it. **while shared memory between processes is SPECTRE prone which is a security issue**. So, TCP is the solution to go despite its heavy performance penalty. Or go for threads instead of processes, but threads may have other problems, but it has better performance.

Comment: Also you can use any event loop library like `libuv` (C) or `boost::asio` (C++) on the UI process instead of sleeping, you can just post an event that tries the semaphore and do actions only if it is available, and retries it later if it is currently locked. Also `libuv` and `boost::asio` will help you use the TCP approach if you want.

Comment: @RichThis is not an interview question. Its related to a project I am working on.

Comment: @user9335240: Error prone how? Will it resolved by using semaphores for shared memory access? The system will be inaccessible to the outside world, only the UI application will be exposed to the user. I cannot use threads, as the other program has to run independently. I need to put as less load as possible on the CPU as I have other modules which rely heavily on the CPU.
I will look into "event loop" 
Thanks

Comment: @Rhnbmpl I say shared memory between THREADS are error prone, but shared memory between PROCESSES is more dangerous, it is a security breach called SPECTRE on Intel processors, https://meltdownattack.com/.     In JavaScript for example, Google Chrome and Firefox allowed shared memory between different pages (using processes under the hood), and removed this functionality when Spectre was discovered because it is dangerous. I don't know for sure how, but it seems shared memory between processes is buggy, it could be exploited to reach isolated parts, like passwords.

Comment: @user9335240 : can it be exploited if I don't give any writing access to users accessing my system? Only services that I expose to the users through UI are accessible to the users, other than that they cannot access my system(i.e. run their code in my system or browse the internet with my system, like an embedded application)